# "None of [Index([('PBT', 'Book_Preference')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Have this particular table based on Preferred Book Type(0-10 and Book Preference (0-4) and Target (0 = False, 1 = True):**

| PBT | Book_Preference | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

**THIS WAS MY TARGET:**

```
df["Target"] = (df['PBT']==0.0) & (df['Book_Preference']==0)
df["Target"] = df["Target"].astype(int)
```

**MY SKLEARN:**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_split=100, random_state=1)

train = (df['PBT']==6) & (df['Book_Preference']==1)
test = (df['PBT']==5) & (df['Book_Preference']==0)

predictors = [["PBT", "Voted_For"]]
model.fit(train[predictors], train["Target"])
```

**HOWEVER I GET THIS PROBLEM AFTER RUNNING THE SKLEARN:**

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('PBT', 'Book_Preference')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

**WHAT IS THE ISSUE WITH MY CODE AND HOW DO I SOLVE THIS?**

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
train = (df['PBT']==6) & (df['Book_Preference']==1)
```

`train` here is a boolean Series, you need use that to boolean indexing the dataframe

```py
train = df[(df['PBT']==6) & (df['Book_Preference']==1)]
```

Also you use `predictors = [["PBT", "Voted_For"]]` and select columns like `train[predictors]`. However, to select columns from DataFrame, you need use list not list of list.

```py
predictors = ["PBT", "Voted_For"]
train[predictors]
```